# What is the difference between Silhouette Index vs Dunn Index vs Davies-Bouldin Index

Tags: clustering

I would like to know whether there is any condition that using one cluster evaluation methods (Dunn, Silhouette, Davies-Bouldin) is better than others. I didn't find anything online or inside books, except a short descriptions that Dunn index is good for non-convex shaped clusters, but didn't find a proper justification for this claim.

Comment: They will often prefer the same solutions and the differences are supposedly largely a matter of *subjective* preference.

Comment: For non-convex clusters, DBCV may be more appropriate.

Comment: Please go to my web-page and read "Clustering criterions" documentation. The three criterions are very different in their "ideology"

Answer (score 1):

[Bolshakova and Azuaje (2003)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168402004759) presents an evaluation between the three cluster validation techniques you mention. Maybe this helps if you haven't seen it.

Comment: Thank you for the paper. I go thought it, and it is domain specific (genome data) I would like to know something in general.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry that I couldn't help, then.